# Airflow - Is it possible to run one day at a time(sequentially) using the backfill command?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Basically, I would like to run the backfill command for a whole month. But there are some tasks that depend on the data of the previous day. And as far as I know, this command runs each day at the same time.

```
airflow backfill adsquare_events -s 2017-01-01 -e 2017-01-31
```

Is there a way to make the backfill command to run one day at a time(sequentially)?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you should set the parameter depends_on_past to True on the default args

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'whatever',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 9, 17),
    'email': ['xxxxx'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
}
```

Comment: The 'depends_on_past' property doesn't seem to make each DagRun wait for the previous DagRun to complete. Instead, it seems that each task waits for the related task in the previous DagRun so the result is 'task 1' of run 2 starts concurrently with 'task 2' of run 1... My problem is that each DagRun uses the same staging bucket/table for each run, so they interfere...

Answer (score 0):

Put ExternalTaskSensor as a first step:

```
ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_yesterday_run',
    external_dag_id='adsquare_events',
    execution_delta=timedelta(days=1),
    execution_date_fn=None,
    dag=dag,
)
```